# Converting std::array of std::string to std::tuple of the same size using boost::lexical_cast

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost

I want to create a function that takes array of strings and converts it to tuple by doing lexical_cast on each of array elements.

std::array size is the same as std::tuple size and all tuple types are known at compile time

For example:

```
std::tuple<int, double> Result = Convert({"1", "1.0"});
```

or

```
int A, B;
std::tie(A, B) = Convert({"1", "2"});
```

How can I do that with acceptable performace and without c++14 support?

Comment: What is the question? You already specified how you want to do it.. Implement the necessary streaming operators. Also, I fail to see the std::array in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do

```
namespace detail
{

    template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t N, std::size_t...Is>
    std::tuple<Ts...>
    Convert(const std::array<std::string, N>& s,
            std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return std::tuple<Ts...>{boost::lexical_cast<Ts>(s[Is])...};
    }

}

template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t N>
std::tuple<Ts...> Convert(const std::array<std::string, N>& s)
{
    static_assert(N == sizeof...(Ts), "Unexpected size");
    return detail::Convert<Ts...>(s, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>());
}
```

With usage:

```
std::array<std::string, 2u> ns = {"1", "4.2"};
auto t = Convert<int, double>(ns);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/NnjYf6)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to provide the types you want to convert into. As in:

```
std::tuple<int, double> Result = Convert<int, double>({"1", "1.0"});
```

With that, it's not so bad:

```
template <typename... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> Convert(const std::array<std::string, sizeof... (Ts)>& arr ) {
    return Convert<Ts...>(arr, make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{} );
}

template <typename... Ts, typename... Is>
std::tuple<Ts...> Convert(const std::array<std::string, sizeof... (Ts)>& arr, index_sequence<Is...> ) {
    return std::make_tuple(boost::lexical_cast<Ts>(arr[Is])...));
}
```

There are several C++11 implementations of the index sequence trick on SO.